# $T^{0}_{0}$ element of Energy-Momentum tensor derivation from a Lagrangian

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, lagrangian-formalism, stress-energy-momentum-tensor

I'm new here. Given the Lagrangian,

$ L=\frac{1}{2}∂_{μ}\Phi (∂^{μ}\Phi)^{*} − \frac{λ}{4}(\Phi\Phi^{*} - 1)^{2}$

and its energy-momentum tensor

$T^{\mu}_{\nu}=\frac{\partial L}{\partial(\partial^{\mu}\Phi^{*})}\partial_{\nu} \Phi -δ^{μ}_{ν}L $

For the element $T^{0}_{0}$ I get

$T^{0}_{0}=\frac{1}{2}\dot{\Phi}^{2}+\frac{1}{2}(\nabla{\Phi})^{2}+\frac{λ}{4}(\Phi\Phi^{*} - 1)^{2}$

Which seems to be incorrect, could anyone help me find the correct answer?  Thank you for your time!!

Comment: The correct formula for the energy momentum tensor is $T^\mu{}_\nu = \frac{ \partial L }{ \partial ( \partial^\mu \Phi ) } \partial_\nu \Phi + \frac{ \partial L }{ \partial ( \partial^\mu \Phi^* ) } \partial_\nu \Phi^* - \delta^\mu_\nu L$. Also, for canonically normalized fields, your Lagrangian should be $L = \partial_\mu \Phi ( \partial^\mu \Phi )^* - \frac{\lambda}{4} ( \Phi \Phi^* - 1 )^2$.

Comment: Thank you very much @Prahar !! I'm new to field theory so I have still some questions, I get the expression $\frac{\partial(\partial_{μ} \Phi(\partial^{μ} \Phi)^{*})}{\partial(\partial^{μ}\Phi)}\partial_{ν} \Phi$ what does this differentiation equal to?

Comment: It is $(\partial_\mu \Phi)^* \partial_\nu \Phi$.

Comment: Yes. There is! I made a mistake in my earlier formula. The correct index structure is $T_{\mu\nu} = \frac{ \partial L }{ \partial ( \partial^\mu \Phi )} \partial_\nu \Phi  +  \frac{ \partial L }{ \partial ( \partial^\nu \Phi^* )} \partial_\mu \Phi^*  - \eta_{\mu\nu} L$. To obtain $T^\mu_\nu$ you can now just raise the $\mu$ index.

Comment: First of all, what you have written is not true. What is true is $\frac{ \partial ( \partial_\mu \Phi  (\partial^\mu \Phi)^* )}{  \partial (\partial^\mu \Phi ) } \partial_\nu \Phi = \partial_\mu \Phi^* \partial_\nu \Phi$. Next, since $\eta^{\mu\nu}$ does not depend on the field $\Phi$ there is no problem with perform any contraction with it.

Comment: @Prahar ok that is the first term I agree no problem with that, but isn't there the second term $\frac{\partial(\partial_{μ}Φ(\partial^{μ}Φ)^{*})}{\partial(\partial^{ν}Φ^{*})}\partial_{μ}Φ^{*}$, what is that equal to then?

Comment: I have written an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct canonical normalized Lagrangian should be
$$
L = ( \partial^\mu \Phi)^*( \partial_\mu  \Phi )  - \frac{\lambda}{4} ( \Phi^* \Phi - 1 )^4 \,.
$$
The canonical energy momentum tensor is
$$
T^\mu{}_\nu = \frac{\partial L }{ \partial( \partial_\mu \Phi ) } \partial_\nu \Phi + \frac{\partial L }{ \partial( (\partial_\mu \Phi)^* ) } (\partial_\nu \Phi)^* - \delta^\mu_\nu L .
$$
Applying this to the Lagrangian at hand, we find
$$
T^\mu{}_\nu = (\partial^\mu \Phi)^* \partial_\nu \Phi + \partial^\mu \Phi ( \partial_\nu \Phi )^* - \delta^\mu_\nu  \left[ ( \partial^\alpha \Phi)^*( \partial_\alpha  \Phi )  - \frac{\lambda}{4} ( \Phi^* \Phi - 1 )^4 \right]
$$

Comment: I can't begin to thank you enough!!! Have a great day!!

Answer (score 1):

You aren't applying the energy-momentum tensor in the right way. You should sum over both fields. Check again your formula!

Edit: You have to consider the complex field like an other field.

Edit2: The correct formula is given by
$$T^\mu_{\nu} = \frac{\partial L}{\partial (\partial_\mu \phi_a)}\partial_\nu \phi_a - \delta_\nu^\mu L $$
where you have to sum over all fiels $\phi_a = \{\Phi, \Phi^*\}$.

Comment: Would you mind writing down the right expression? I'm having trouble understanding what you are saying.

Comment: Sorry to bother you but could you write the correct expression for the energy-momentum tensor regarding 2 fields then?

Comment: Ok done, I edited my post. I hope it is clear now.